# Macro to look up value in sheet 2 from a cell in sheet 1, and input date into corresponding row in sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I'm really new to VBA, and could do with your help please.

Sheet2 is a long list of data (jobs) where each row in column B contains a unique job reference number.

I want users to input one of these numbers into a cell in Sheet 1 (G11), then the macro searches Sheet2ColumnB for the number, goes across 21 cells in that same row, then enters today's date and time into that cell. 
(It then goes back to Sheet1 and says "Job Booked Out" but I think I can do this bit)

I've tried to modify some other code I've found, but get errors in the 4th line, and I have no clue if it works.

```
Sub CloseJob()
Dim cell As Range
Dim temp As Range
For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.cell("G11").Cells
        If cell <> "" And cell.Row <> 1 Then
        Set temp = Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("B").Find(What:=cell.Value, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
        'if found
        If Not temp Is Nothing Then
            'if the search_criteria is in the same sheet
            cell.Offset(0, 21) = Date
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Error:

"Run-time error 483. Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You should kindly provide any error messages.

Comment: "Run-time error 483.  Object doesn't support this property or method"    Thanks for looking!

Comment: I don't get the point of using the For-Each-Loop here. If you want to look up the value, which is written in cell G11 in Sheet 1, you can just pass this value into a variable. However, the loop declaration itself is wrong. You don't provide a proper range to loop through. That is (partially) causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by your narrative you seem after this:

```
Sub CloseJob()
    Dim temp As Range
    Set temp = Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("B").Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G11").Value, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
    'if found
    If Not temp Is Nothing Then temp.Offset(0, 21) = Date
End Sub
```

notice I changed `LookAt:=xlPart` to `LookAt:=xlWhole` for an exact match

Comment: Amazing!!!  it works!  You guys are fantastic-  thank you DisplayName....  That code is much simpler... I need to spend some time properly learning VBA and not just fudging around the edges ;-)

Comment: Hi, just one modification -  How would i also copy a value from G12 in Sheet 1, into the cell in the next column along from where the date has just been entered?   Thank you @DisplayName - you have a place in a heaven of your choosing!

Comment: Hi @DisplayName, in case you didn't see my requested addition, please check comment above... also, can if it cannot find the number, can it give a message in Sheet1 Cell G15 like "Number not found" ?

Comment: ^ asked as a new question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Test and I will be able to get connect with like minded peopl